# error: environment has no access-key or secret-key

Tags: ssh, juju

I just installed a **juju enviornment**, which required me to make this **ssh-key** prerequisite for later on,

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048

But I think I made a fatal error by leaving the file to save the key in *empty* and not adding a *passphrase*. I did this since I haven't configured juju yet, also the fact I'm not familiar with either software. I installed and confiruged juju fine, until I tried to bootstrap, which gave me this fatal error,

> error: environment has no access-key or secret-key

I know this points to this, but how do I point the ssh-key to juju? Here some info about the key from when I created it, if it's any helpful,

> Your identification has been saved in /home/donovan/.ssh/id_rsa. Your
>   public key has been saved in /home/donovan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. The key
>   fingerprint is: d3:b5:ea:0a:29:d4:05:9b:1e:08:a9:0e:0e:ca:d6:81

Answer (score 2):

the error message about access-key/secret-key aren't about your ssh-key they are about your cloud provider credentials (in this case ec2). You must provide the your ec2 credentials either via the environment variablse AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY or via the configuration in environments.yaml.